# epsilon parameter in Adam opitmizer

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, adam

Using pyTorch and tensorflow (TF), I was wandering how the Adam optimizer is implemented for curiosity. And I do not know if I am wrong or not but it seems to me that the two implementations differ and the pyTorch one is the original one from https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6980.pdf.

My problem comes from the eps-parameter. Using the TF implentation seems to lead to a time-and-b2 dependance of this parameter, namely

```
q(t+1) = q(t) - \gamma * sqrt[(1-b2^t)]/(1-b1^t) * m(t)/[sqrt[v(t)]+eps]
```

which in the original algorithm notation can be reformulate as

```
 q(t+1) = q(t) - \gamma * mhat(t)/[sqrt[vhat(t)]+ eps/sqrt[(1-b2^t)]]
```

and this point out the variation of the eps-parameter which is not the case neither in the original algorithm neither in the pyTorch implementation.

Am I wrong? or it is well known? 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, you can check this [in the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/AdamOptimizer) for the TF Adam optimizer. To quote the relevant part:

> The default value of 1e-8 for epsilon might not be a good default in general. For example, when training an Inception network on ImageNet a current good choice is 1.0 or 0.1. Note that since AdamOptimizer uses the formulation just before Section 2.1 of the Kingma and Ba paper rather than the formulation in Algorithm 1, the "epsilon" referred to here is "epsilon hat" in the paper.

If you check the "the formulation just before section 2.1" in the paper, they actually include the time dependence in `alpha`, resulting in a time-dependent "step size" `alpha_t` but a fixed `epsilon`. Note that at the end of the day, this is just rewriting/interpreting parameters in a slightly different fashion and doesn't change the actual workings of the algorithm. But you *will* need to be aware that choosing the same `epsilon` in the PyTorch and TF implementations will apparently not lead to the same results...

Comment: Cool! If this answer helped you, consider upvoting and accepting so others can see, as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can derive the formula from the second to the first as following. So in the tensorflow implementation, the epsilon is actually the epsilon' here. Also, in the tensorflow implementation, the learning rate is adjusted to alpha' in the following formula. Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: I agree with this derivation, but am confused: the epsilon' in this answer (epsilon hat in the paper) is time-dependent, because of the beta_2^t.  So this epsilon "constant" that tf uses is in fact not a constant.  So is the tf implementation incorrect?

Comment: Update: I think this is actually the incorrect interpretation and that tensorflow is correct.  While the math above is sound, I believe that what the authors intended was for epsilon hat to simply be a constant. (Which of course is not the same as the original constant epsilon, thus the difference between the pytorch and tf implementations and hyperparameters.)  In other words, the two versions are simply two slightly different versions of the same algorithm, and are **not** intended to be exactly equivalent as in this answer's interpretation.